# Create table in oracle similar to a given csv file and populate it

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a csv file with more than 100 columns and I want to create a table in oracle with the similar structure, then populate it.

Do you have any idea how to do this ? ( SQL*Loader, External tables, ..)
I don't want to use the classic " Create table " and specify for each column the name and type.

Comment: You still have to create the table and give the column names and types/sizes; before you run SQL*Loader, or as part of the `create table ... organisation external` command. How are you proposing Oracle would know/guess that information? I suppose you could do it outside the DB by analysing the file and pulling, say the column headers and the maximum length of values in each column, and generate a `create table` command from that. Or even in the DB by pulling the file in with `UTL_FILE`, and then using dynamic SQL. But seems like a lot of overhead either way, when you could just type it in.

Comment: You can also use excel functions, such as `CONCATENATE` to create the `create table ...` command

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but does it work:
If you don't want to specify column names, you can import you CSV in Access.
Then, after you have defined a DSN, you can export your table to Oracle.